# Animate CSS display

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Is there a way to animate the CSS display property in jQuery? I have the following:

```
$(".maincontent").css("display","block");
```

and want it to do something like this:

```
$(".maincontent").animate({"display": "block"}, 2500);
```

Comment: Could you use opacity?

Comment: how about [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with using animate on display?

Are you trying to fadeIn your .maincontent div?

Comment: the element is currently displayed none. i would like the element to have a delay before it shows. fadein doesnt quite achieve this.

Comment: You can use `.delay()` method. I.E: `$(".maincontent").delay(2500).show();` Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can you not just use something like `$(".maincontent").delay(2500).show();`

Comment: Can you not use fadein and fadeout methods?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just use `.show()` passing it a parameter:

```
$(".maincontent").show(2500);
```

**Edit (based on comments)**:

The above code fades in the element over a 2.5 second span.  If instead you want a 2.5 second delay and then want the element to display, use the following:

```
$(".maincontent").delay(2500).fadeIn();
```

If, of course, you want a delay and a longer fade, just pass the number of milliseconds desired into each method.

Comment: Thanks Derek, i have already tried this. But its not quite the effect i am looking for,

Comment: @danyo, what precisely are you looking for?  `.show()` simply changes the CSS display to 'block'.  Are you looking for something else?

Comment: yes thats what i need, but would like a short delay rather than it being instant.

Comment: @danyo, okay, I just want to make sure I understand.  The code I've given you slowly fades in over 2.5 seconds but begins teh fadein right away. Is what you want: nothing to happen for x amount of time delay and then fade in over y amount of time?

Comment: The thing about opacity is that if you use a class on multiple divs, it will affect them and then it starts bugging, like I have several <li> elements with <img> in it, and using the opacity affects all of the <li> elements and they also change the style with the first one...this does not happened on the firefox but the bug is present on every other browser...

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
$("div").css({
    "opacity":"0",
    "display":"block",
}).show().animate({opacity:1})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/g7z6m/

This takes into account the `display:none`, since it will still be removed from the flow of the page until the code is invoked, where it will display it, then set it's opacity to 0. It will then animate it's opacity to 1 when you call the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (as I mentioned in comments):

You can use `.delay()` method. I.E:

```
$(".maincontent").delay(2500).show();
```

Comment: I'm trying to work this out, TheOverlay.delay(300).css({"display":"block"});

but it just skips the delay :/

Answer (score 0):

Animating opacity using jQuery is more viable than display property, here the opacity is animated from 0 to 1 in 1 second:

```
$(".maincontent").animate({opacity:1},1000)
```

Then the css should be like this:

```
.maincontent{ 
opacity: 0;
}
```

If you are planning to hide the entire block before the transistion, you could have a display property.

```
.maincontent{
opacity: 0;
display: none;
}
```

Then to show the block with animation:

```
$(".maincontent").show().animate({opacity:1},1000 function(){
  (callback function here)
})
```

Hope this helps!