# Slide Div up and down on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

On click of a tag the div opens and close accordingly. What i want is that the div should slide down and up slowly instead of showing up immediately.

```
<a href="" class="accordion">Click here</a>
 <div class="panel" id="AccordionDiv">
            <div class="store">
                <div class="store-row">

                    <div class="cells store-logo text-center">
                        <img src="@strStaticWebsiteUrl@(objOfferPrice.StoreImage)" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    @if (objOfferPrice.Price < objOfferPrice.UrlPrice)
                    {
                        <div class="cells text-center">
                            <div class="product-price offer-price">Rs. @String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0,0}", objOfferPrice.Price)<sup>*</sup></div>
                            <p class="real-price">Price: @objOfferPrice.UrlPrice</p>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
           </div>
```

This is html code and below is the Script code.

```
            <script>
                var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                            panel.style.display = "none";
                        } else {
                            panel.style.display = "block";
                        }
                    });
                        }
            </script>
```

Comment: you should just add or remove a class on the div, and less css do the sliding up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate CSS display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863490/animate-css-display)

Comment: You can use toggle function http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use CSS

CSS animations look a lot better than Javascript animation, also. CSS animations can be canceled/reversed half way.

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("slideActive");
        });
    }
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.accordion {
    height: 0px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.accordion .slideActive{
    height: 100px;
}
```

*(Or whatever styling you may prefer)*

---

You can check if it's `active`, by using:

```
this.classList.contains('slideActive');
```

Comment: Updated. Try this.

Comment: in the script you have used active too but you removed that from css

Comment: this.classList.toggle("active");  how would this line work

Comment: Yeah, I tried to keep your code mostly intact, however the CSS should be applied to the `nextSibbling` element, right? So I added a `slideActive` class. But you can remove the `active` toggle I guess.

Comment: and than if loop should i check this.classList.contains('slideActive'); or toggle will do the work?

Comment: `.toggle()` toggles the class on click. So you can set styling through CSS when this class is applied. The `.contains()` checks if the class is active at the moment. You do not need it for the toggle, it was just some extra info which you can instead of the `if.. else..` you currently did.

Comment: Thank you sir.    var Accordion = this.nextElementSibling;
                    $(Accordion).slideToggle();
          This is what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) method that jQuery provides for this effect

```
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
$(panel).slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have Animation in JQuery "slideDown", slideUp and slideToggle.

```
$( "#ID1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
    // Animation slow slideDown.
  });
});
```

Same we can use with slideUp.

And "slideToggle" is for Up and Down both.