# jQuery Toggle Display none and animate.css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

I have a div that is initially hidden by display: none in the css.

```
<div id="myDiv" class="animate__animated">Div content Here</div>
```

I this have a function:

```
function togglefunc() {

    $('#myDiv').toggle().toggleClass('animate__slideInRight animate__slideInLeft');

}
```

What I want to do is to toggle display: none and block but also toggle classes:

```
animate__slideInRight and animate__slideInLeft
```

So...

If it's hidden and the function is called, it shows up with the effect animate__slideInRight (animate.css class)

otherwise

If it's visible and the function is called, it will hide with the effect animate__slideInLeft (animate.css class)

My function shows fine with the effect animate__slideInRight but when I click again if quickly hides with no effect.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate CSS display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863490/animate-css-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the jquery toggle is done inmediatelly and not after the hide animation triggered by the attribute change is done.

I would instead use just jQuery for this slide effect:

```js
function togglefunc() {
   $("#myDiv").animate({width: "toggle"}, 350);
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="togglefunc()">Toggle</button><br><br>
<div id="myDiv" class="animate__animated">Div content Here</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Sadly, you can't animate an element going from `display: none` to `display: block`. You can however use `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`.