# why transition doesn't work on my dom actions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am implementing a project and I want when my `checkbox` is `checked`, the books name and the button get hidden, but when I want to add `transition` to this process it doesn't get applied, so what's wrong with that?
P.N: I have the same issue with transition while I want to add or delete a book by dom.

code:

```js
//JS
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
//deletion
let main=document.querySelector("main");
main.addEventListener("click",event=>{
if(event.target.matches(".bookButton")){
event.target.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(event.target.parentElement)
//event.target.parentElement.style.transition="all 10s";
}
});



//hide section
let hide=document.querySelector(".hide input[type=checkbox]");
hide.addEventListener("change",()=>{
if(hide.checked) main.style.display="none";
else main.style.display="initial";
})
```

```css
//CSS
/*main*/
main{
transition: display 1s;
}

.book{
display: grid;
grid-template: 1fr/repeat(2,1fr);
justify-items: center;
align-items: center;

}

.bookText{
grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 1;
font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.bookButton{
grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 2;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.hide{
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
margin:.5rem 0 .8rem 0;
}
.hide label{
margin-left: .5rem;
font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
//HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./cssPage.css">
<!--rel role-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./normalize.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Book your book here!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="adjust">
<div class="whole">
<header>
    <h1 id="header">Book Booking Site</h1>
    <h2 id="sub-text">Add and Delete Books Here!</h2>
    <form action="" class="search">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Search here...">
    </form>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="book">
        <p class="bookText" >Harry Potter</p>
        <button class="bookButton">Delete</button>
    </div>
        
    <div class="book">
        <p class="bookText">Lord of The Ring</p>
        <button class="bookButton">Delete</button>
    </div>    
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="hide">
            <input type="checkbox" id="hide">
            <label for="hide">Hide All</label>
        </div>
    </footer>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="javascriptPage.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `display` is [non-animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) but [there are workarounds](https://www.taccgl.org/blog/css_transition_display.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only transition properties that use numerical values (such as `width`, `opacity`, `flex-grow`, `color`, etc.) - [[extensive list of CSS animateable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)]. For example, the `display` property in CSS is not one of those properties, hence you cannot transition removing or adding elements to the DOM.

You can find this info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#which_css_properties_can_be_transitioned).

Comment: isn't there any solution for making these process like adding and displaying more smooth?

Comment: You can animate,for example,max-height. To make something disappear set max-height to 0 and animate that instead.  If you're open to using a library then you can animate show and hide using [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863490/animate-css-display)